# Angular Markdown Parsing "\n" Newline Characters Issue

Tags: javascript, html, angular, markdown

I've created a blog where markdown is returned as a string from my backend, however when I return a string with the correct newline characters it does not behave as expected.

I am using [ngx-markdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-markdown) to handle parsing of markdown characters, and using the `ngPreserveWhitespaces` attribute to ensure this should be functioning as expected.

Example:

```
// Example #1 Returned String
"## This is a subheader\n This is a sentence"

// Output
<h2>This is a subheader\n This is a sentence</h2>
```

It displays it as a single line with the newline character physically rendered as text, as above.

However within any of my Angular components I can literally write this same string as a property on the component and return it, and it renders correctly like so:

```
// Example #2 Hard Coded String
public correct: string = "## This is a subheader\n This is a sentence";

// Output

<h2>This is a subheader</h2>

<p>This is a sentence</p>
```

As mentioned, the markdown parser I am using is implemented as such:

```
<markdown ngPreserveWhitespaces>{{content}}</markdown>
```

I have also attempted to do this by setting `ngPreserveWhitespaces` within the main/tsconfig files. However I do not believe this is what the issue is, as I can (natively in JS) console.log both my returned string (#1) and the hard coded string (#2) and even my damn logs display differently (with the latter formatting correctly and the former just stringifying the output).

I have attempted:

- JSON stringify/parsing the data in multiple ways (as well as without)
- I have attempted using regex to manually replace characters
- I have attempted to just manually use `<br />`
- I have tried everything outlined [here](https://github.com/jfcere/ngx-markdown/issues/94) regarding this markdown parser handling whitespace (which I do not believe is the issue)

Nothing appears to appease the newline gods.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

Okay so I've found my solution to this, I am now storing my markdown string as such:

```
"## This is a subheader\n This is a sentence"
```

This difference here is the interface I'm storing this within (a Mongo db) puts the speechmarks around string values already, so it now actually looks like this:

```
""## This is a subheader\n This is a sentence""
```

Which is more a weird thing with MongoDB Compass than with what I was attempting.

From this, I am able to JSON.parse the value correctly (previously it was attempting to do so with a string that wasn't valid JSON as it wasn't enclosed in double speechmarks).

I am now handling this in an extension of a `Property` class I have for each of these called `HtmlProperty` which when instantiated, parses the value correctly.

Comment: I have raised a ticket with MongoDB Compass to restyle their String data interface so it doesn't make it look like strings actually have speech marks/double speech marks enclosing them when they do not.